# How do I skip a line/iteration if it produces an error?

Tags: perl, error-handling

I am using [Bio::PopGen::PopStats](http://p3rl.org/Bio%3a%3aPopGen%3a%3aPopStats) to calculate [Wright's F<sub>st</sub>](http://enwp.org/F-statistics) for each line I read in my input file. My input file consists of about 500,000 lines, so I calculate this statistic 500,000 times, as follows:

```
use Bio::PopGen::PopStats;
my $stats = Bio::PopGen::PopStats->new();
my $fst = $stats->Fst(\@populations,\@markernames);
push(@fsts, $fst);
```

I save each F<sub>st</sub> value in the array `@fsts` because in the end I use all 500,000 Fsts to calculate some summary statistics.

If the module fails to calculate the F<sub>st</sub> for one of the 500,000 lines, the whole Perl script stops and gives an error message, usually this one:

```
Illegal division by zero at /usr/share/perl5/Bio/PopGen/PopStats.pm line 292, <READ2> line 10878.
```

I would like my program to give this error message, but instead of stopping, just skip this line (put nothing in the `@fsts` array for this line), and finish the rest of the 500,000 lines. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to trap fatal errors:

```
my $fst;
eval {
    $fst = $stats->Fst(\@populations,\@markernames);
    push @fsts, $fst;
    1;
} or warn $@;
```

Comment: `eval {...; 1} or warn $@` is a safer way to use eval.  `$@` should be true after a failed eval, but there are a few rare cases where it won't be.  But a failed eval will always return false, so if you make it return true on success, then the eval becomes a boolean wrt its status.

Comment: @Eric: can you provide an example of such case?

Comment: @daxim: it should not be the case for Perl 5.14

Comment: Then teach [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny) next time, so we have a better interface and don't need to pay attention to Perl version numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Use an `eval BLOCK`:

```
my $fst = eval {
         $fst = $stats->Fst(\@populations,\@markernames)
         push(@fsts, $fst);
    } or {
         print $@;
    };
```

Comment: You are not pushing the result properly.

Comment: Still same problem. `$fst` is pushed before it's assigned to.